# Python beautifulsoup find_all can‘t find <div class=“ ”>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulsoup to find content in HTML tags.
But when the tags are /**div class=" "**/ , it doesn't work.
It cannot be recognized correctly when there is a **space** in double quotation marks.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
if __name__ == "__main__":
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1946.html", encoding='utf-8'), 'lxml')
for k in (soup.find_all('div', class_=" ")):
    print(k)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `whitespace` is the delimiter in a list of class names, so you wont find it. Just remove the `whitespace` from your selection to get your result and take look at the output, cause that is the way it would be recognised by the parser.

**Note:** *It will interpret it in the way, that there is no class available. So you may have to change your selector strategy and use other attributes or elements - Question needs improvement / example to get more specific answers.*

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div>a</div>
<div class>b</div>
<div class="">c</div>
<div class=" ">d</div>
<div class="x ">x</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for k in (soup.find_all('div', class_="")):
    print(k)
```

#### Output

```
<div>a</div>
<div class="">b</div>
<div class="">c</div>
<div class="">d</div>
```